# How to restrict name changes in Telegram groups

Tags: telegram

We have recently shifted from WhatsApp to Telegram.  We are about 250+ and growing.  The peculiar problem with Telegram is that user names can be changed by the user and that poses a great problem for us. That is, any user can post a nasty comment with a  different user name.  I seek suggestion from community as to how do we restrict this.